# Adapting a fixed-sized chunk pool allocator to certain STL containers

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, stl

I have a pool allocator I wrote as an exercise, which implements the C++11 std::allocator requirements up and running which works OK, but the policy I used as a reference (based on the following paper):

https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/4321/a91d635d023ab25a743c698be219edcdb1a3.pdf

is only really good for allocating a single object into one block of memory with sufficient size for it at a time.

I notice that the std::allocator template method "allocate" has a parameter where STL containers can request a count of blocks to allocate simultaneously. For example it looks like std::basic_string, once it exceeds a certain size string it keeps on the stack, moves the whole thing over to the heap at once by requesting a contiguous block of memory from the allocator large enough to store a char array holding the entire string. std::vector's dynamic expansion seems to work in a similar way.

Is there any way to adapt an allocator designed to return fixed-size chunks the size of the type it's templated on to this type of STL container?

Comment: A standard allocator needs to be able to allocate contiguous storage for a specified number of items of the type its templated on.

Comment: You can provide the (optional) member `size_type max_size()`, and throw when it is violated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could go down this route:

```
On the other hand, multiple instances of numerous fixed-sized
pools can be used to produce a general overall flexible
general solution to work in place of the current system
memory manager.
```

And treat each different-sized request as a request for a new pool, i.e. your "object size" is actually object*count.
You will burn a lot of RAM.
You could put an upper bound on the array size, and fall back to default generic allocation above that.

Comment: I noticed that my implementation seems to be generic enough that I can put allocators within allocators, i.e. create a memory pool of N memory pools that themselves allocate contiguous blocks of storage large enough to hold an array of characters for say std::basic_string. Unfortunately std::basic_string expects its allocator to be templated on a character type, not say a pointer to an array of char, so I'd have to figure a way to modify the implementation so its block size is large enough to return contiguous storage when templated on a basic type

Comment: Add a second parameter to the allocate function, which is the number of units.